# Почему меш после риггинга при повороте некоректно накладывается на скелет?

Tags: blender

после риггинга и настройки весов я столкнулся с такой проблемой
[image: 11111]

и так чисто со всеми конечностями, и не только конечностями

и я не понимаю, как это исправить, как сделать так, чтобы меш ложился корректно на скелет?

если что меш это одна моделька, не отдельные части, хз зачем уточняю.